# Позиционирование в Android

Tags: java, android, изображения, button, bitmap

Вот мой код .xml:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--Normal Screen-->
 
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/Relative"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/imageViewBg"/>
    
    <ru.xmarkt.flashlight.button.VerticalSeekBar
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="145dp"
            android:layout_x="150dp"
            android:layout_y="200dp"
            android:id="@+id/vertical_Seekbar"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:thumb="@drawable/button_normal"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/style_seekbar"
            android:layout_marginBottom="65dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/adView"
            android:thumbOffset="12dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Не судите строго, но цель, понять как позиционировать вертикальный `SeekBar`(для поддержки устройств *Android 2.3*) относительно фонового изображения(`ImageView id=imageViewBg` ), чтобы они были расположены относительно друг друга в одном месте, в зависимости от разрешений экрана.

Перепробовал различные варианты, но увы не получилось. Есть мысли или идеи, как это можно сделать? Буду рад любой поддержке.

Да, также скину свой класс `SeekBar`:

```
public class VerticalSeekBar extends SeekBar {

public VerticalSeekBar(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public VerticalSeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attributeSet, defStyle);

}

public VerticalSeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(h, w, oldh, oldw);
}

@Override
protected synchronized void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(heightMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
    setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredHeight(), getMeasuredWidth());
}
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.rotate(-90);
    canvas.translate(-getHeight(),0);
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}


@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (!isEnabled()) {
        return false;
    }
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            setProgress(getMax() - (int) (getMax() * event.getY() / getHeight()));
            onSizeChanged(getWidth(), getHeight(), 0, 0);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            if(getProgress() >= getMax()/2){
                setProgress(getMax());
                onSizeChanged(getWidth(), getHeight(), 0, getHeight());
            }
            else{
                setProgress(0);
                onSizeChanged(getWidth(), 0, 0, getHeight());
            }
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

}

Фотки также прикрепляю, как примерно я хочу чтобы выглядело мое приложение:

[image: Основной фон и слайд-кнопка]
`SeekBar` использует в качестве `thumb` кнопку, таким образом получается слайд кнопка. Высоту бара тоже нужно отрегулировать в зависимости от изображения фонового, чтобы оно равнялось впадине по центру.